# Ubuntu 20.04 UBS Bluetooth 5.0 - Working Devices List

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth

My first posting - UBUNTU newbie, but I am learning fast.

I have installed UB 20.04 onto my old Thinkpad T61 - with a 120GB SSD and 8GB RAM.  Installed like a breeze.  I am hoping to make this a replacement for my HomeSeer system on another Thinkpad running Windows 7.

I would really like to have BT 5.0 working on this laptop for the HomeSeer system.  I bought one of these [USB Bluetooth Adapter for PC, QGOO Mini Bluetooth 5.0 EDR Dongle for Desktop Computer][1]  -  I got it yesterday, and oddly found after installing in the laptop - it does not work.  I went back and did more research and found not supported in Linux.  :-(

I can see it if I run the lsusb command:

```
root@UB-ThinkPad-T61:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 STMicroelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I did a little research to find this command, but not finding any way to get it to turn ON.  in Settings, it shows  "No Bluetooth Found - plug in a dongle".

Any help is appreciated - I can return this one, and get one which works...provided I can get a list of supported USB BT5.0 adapters.

Thanks in advance,
Curtis

Comment: [Edimax BT-8500](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/bluetooth/bt-8500/). The official website claims that it's supported by Linux kernel 2.6.32 - 5.3. I found a [reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/jundu8/any_recommendations_for_bluetooth_adapters/gcee6sj/) who bought it and says it works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: [Asus USB BT500](https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-BT500/techspec/) claims to have Linux support, but doesn't list kernel versions.

Comment: Just to update, I bought the Edimax BT-8500 dongle today and can confirm that it works with Ubuntu 20.04.2 with kernel version 5.11.0-40. It works out of the box, but I did have to go into sound settings to change the output configuration from "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" to "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" to make stereo audio work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a long research document with the currently supported Bluetooth 5+ adapters on Linux. [You can read the full report here on medium](https://opengears.medium.com/bluetooth-5-on-linux-overview-of-kernel-supported-dongles-and-chipsets-c6f2b632b236), in a nutshell, here are the devices I can recommend:

- USB: Realtek RTL8761B, RTL8761BU and RTL8852BE. A good trick is to search for USB dongles which are supporting RaspberryPi, as you might be able to find different ones as well.
- NGFF: Intel AX210 - but be careful about CNVio and CNVio2 (depends on your notebook!)
- PCIe: you can use NGFF adapters, so you can use these in your stationary machines.